# How to echo a variable in woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Below is my function. But I can't seem to see my echo on any pages.

```
function add_qr_number_to_order_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $qr_code = generate_qr_number($user_id);
        $item->add_meta_data( 'qr_code', $qr_code );

        echo "QR: " . $qr_code; 

    } else {
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_qr_number_to_order_item', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: try doing a `dd("QR: " . $qr_code);` - this will dump out what you're looking for and make the application die, so you would definitely be able to see if you're in the right section of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 1**

1) This hook is not made to display anything or redirect user, it is made to save (or alter) **order line items** meta data… 
So you should better use instead in your case the hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` to add a QR code based on user ID, as order metadata…

2) To get the user ID use `$order->get_user_id()` *(if the user Id is `0` user is **not** logged in and else it is logged in)*.

**Assuming that your custom function `generate_qr_number()` works**, the correct code should be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_qr_code', 10, 2 );
function save_order_item_qr_code( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $user_id = (int) $order->get_user_id();

    if ( $user_id > 0 ){
        $qr_code = generate_qr_number($user_id);
        $order->update_meta_data( 'qr_code', $qr_code );
    }
}
```

To check if the QR code is saved you can use the following to display it in admin order edit pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_qr_code_to_order_admin', 10, 1 );
function display_qr_code_to_order_admin( $order ){
    if( $qr_code = $order->get_meta('qr_code') ){
        echo '<div class="qr-code">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:6px;">
        <tr><th align="left">'.__('QR Code').':&nbsp;</th><td>&nbsp;' . $qr_code . '</td></tr>
        </table></div>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. It should work.

---

**Update 2**

To save it for each order item you should use *(assuming that `generate_qr_number()` function works)*:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_qr_code', 10, 4 );
function save_order_item_qr_code( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $user_id = (int) $order->get_user_id();

    if ( $user_id > 0 ){
        $qr_code = generate_qr_number($user_id);
        $item->update_meta_data( 'Qr code', $qr_code );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first code above but it didn't work. I don't see any qr_code metadata under wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table.

Comment: @worisi24 I have make a little change (a little mistake taken from your code)… Now it's not grabbed in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` but in `wp_postmeta` table, as you need just one qr_code by user and not by order item (so this need to be order meta data, but not order item meta data).

Comment: I actually have to map a QR code to an order item. BTW, I tried to mention your name using @ but it doesn't work

Comment: @worisi24 I have added an update for **order item** Qr code generation save, but as it's based on User ID, this is really not logical…